# Documentation downvote count shade-of-red is too bright

Tags: bug, documentation, design

Q&A:

[image]

Docs:

[image]

I suggest changing the shade of red in Docs to match that of Q&A.

Comment: The shade of green for upvotes is also different, though not as drastically.

Comment: i like the brigher red

Comment: I agree. And if that red is #f00 (pure red) as the screenshot suggests, then against a white background it fails the Tritanope contrast test according to the [Accessibility Color Wheel](http://gmazzocato.altervista.org/colorwheel/wheel.php). The purest red which passes all contrast tests is #ea0000 (which is still a way brighter than the dark red used in Q&A) so the docs red should at least be adjusted to that, if not darker.

Comment: @AdamLear Is it rude to ask if I can get a `status-*` on this?

Comment: @NathanArthur It's not rude, but there's no status tag to be put on this at the moment. :)

Comment: @AdamLear Cool. Thanks!

Comment: doesn't matter.. color blind..

Comment: Would be more consistent, but heck, it's only docs. People who care to read docs read the *actual* docs instead of some garbage that does not even show up on google, so vOv

Comment: this is some kind of joke right? I wonder about Meta at times

Comment: @NaN Meta is all about bikeshedding

Comment: @NaN Good design is all about details, of which accessibility is not an insignificant one. FWIW, posting this took me all of 2 minutes.